# BlueZ DBUS API - GATT interfaces unavailable for BLE device

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, dbus, bluez

I have a BLE device which has a bunch of GATT services running on it. My goal is to access and read data from the service characteristics on this device from a Linux computer (BlueZ version is 5.37). I have enabled experimental mode - therefore, full GATT support should be available. BlueZ's DBUS API, however, only provides the `org.bluez.GattManager1` interface for the connected device, and not the `org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1` or `org.bluez.GattService1` interfaces which I need. Is there something I'm doing wrong? The device is connected and paired, and really I've just run out of ideas as how to make this work, or what may be wrong.

If it helps, I'm using Python and the DBUS module to interface with BlueZ.

Comment: As per bluez [git](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt?h=5.37#n69), we have `GattCharacterstic1` and `GattService1` in Bluez 5.37. Did I miss any thing ? Any way, why not use latest 5.39 ?

Comment: The interfaces don't show up though, that's the problem. I've decided to stick to the stock Ubuntu version instead of upgrading to 5.39, in case it breaks anything.

Comment: Considering that this [tinyb](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb) library depends on 5.37, may be, we are missing some thing?

Comment: I'll take a look at that library - if I have to bring it over to C++, I can. Thanks for linking it, I never knew it even existed!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't show up". I've used the gatt interfaces and can confirm that they work just fine. It's more likely you are not using them correctly but we cannot tell as you have not provided your code.

Comment: They just aren't there in any of the objects. Is there some kind of time limit which I have to endure while BlueZ scans for the services on the device?

Comment: "They just aren't there in any of the objects". Yes, but how are you determining that? How do we know your code isn't wrong? "Is there something I'm doing wrong?" How can we answer that if you don't show us the code so we can see what that "something" is. So please show your code. But for starters I suggest you test with the `bluetoothctl` utility first to eliminate any possible issues with your code. That utility certainly works and will discover the services and characteristics.

Comment: Strangely enough, after a system update the problem seems to have fixed itself :\. I don't know what changed or why, but hey ho.

Comment: Perhaps the issue might have been not starting the `bluetoothd` daemon with the `-E` (for experimental) option. The D-Bus GATT API only stabilized circa [release 5.41](http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-41/) of BlueZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system update resolved this problem.